# What happened or where are the seven Deadly sins in Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I've watched the first episode of Nanatsu no Taizai: Mokushiroku no Yonkishi. They didn't show, and as far as I could tell they didn't mention, any of the seven Deadly Sins.

What happened to them or where are they ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The Four Knights of the Apocalypse* (4KOA) takes place 16 years after the Demon King's defeat, i.e. roughly 6 years after *The Seven Deadly Sins* (7DS) chapter 346 and Special Chapter 6.

As of chapter 124 only two members of the former Seven Deadly Sins have been shown in 4KOA and one more has been mentioned without appearing in person. In short:

1. Gowther has gone incognito while protecting a village of Demon stragglers in the human world (chapter 39).
2. Melodias still rules as King of Liones (chapter 51 and after).
3. Merlin seems to have had a falling out with King Arthur; her whereabouts are unknown (chapter 91).
4. Bam: no update, therefore we must assume that he is still ruling the Kingdom of Benwick (7DS Special Chapter 6).
5. King: no update, therefore we must assume that he's ruling the Kingdom of Fairies and Giants with Diane (7DS chapter 344).
6. Diane: no update, therefore we must assume that she's ruling the Kingdom of Fairies and Giants with King (7DS chapter 344).
7. Escanor: no update, therefore we must assume that he's dead (7DS chapter 333).